# Show Button On Google Marker Drag

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, draggable

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I am using the code below to reverse geocode address details, in this case starting off with the OS Grid Ref.

Could someone perhaps tell me please how I would go about including code which upon the marker being dragged, a button called 'regenerateosgridref' would appear on the form.

```
(function reversegeocodeosgridref() {

    var map, geocoder, latlng, marker;

    window.onload = function() {

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246, -4.45948481875007),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
            },
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
            },
            scaleControl: true,
            scaleControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
            }
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

        var form = document.getElementById('searchforlocationosgridref');

        form.onsubmit = function() {

            var lat = document.getElementById('osgb36lat').value;
            var lng = document.getElementById('osgb36lon').value;

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            getAddress(latlng);

            return false;
        }

    }

    function geocodePosition(pos) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            latLng: pos
        },

        function(responses) {
            if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
                updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
            } else {
                updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
            }
        });
    }

    function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
        document.getElementById('returnedaddress').value = str;
    }

    function getAddress(latlng) {

        if (!geocoder) {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        }

        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': latlng
        }, function(results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                if (results[0]) {

                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    if (!marker) {
                        map.setZoom(16);
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            draggable: true
                        });
                    }
                }

                marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, function() {
                    updateMarkerAddress;
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
                    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
                    document.getElementById('osgb36lat').value = marker.position.lat();
                    document.getElementById('osgb36lon').value = marker.position.lng();

                    var point = marker.getPosition();
                    map.panTo(point);
                });

                latLng = [marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng()].join(', ');
                geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());

                document.getElementById('returnedaddress').value = results[0].formatted_address;
            }
        })
    }
})();
```

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Add a line in your marker `dragend` event that will show the button.

In your dragend event:

```
document.getElementById('regenerateosgridref').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Hi many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post. I've tried this and unfortunately it doesn't work. The button does not start off in a hidden state. Have you any ideas please? Kind regards. Chris

Comment: how does it start? where is your button?

Comment: Hi, the button is within my HTML form and is there to recalculate the OS Grid Ref. once the marker has been dragged. Kind regards. Chris

Comment: If it is on the form and it is not hidden, then it is already visible.

Comment: Hi Alex. Yes I understand what you're saying. I've been looking at my form and the ways in which it will be viewed by the user. What I've decided to do is to run some code that will allow the OS Grid Reference to change as the marker is dragged. It looks a lot neater this way and I think it will be easier for my users. Many thanks for your time and trouble. Kind regards Chris

Answer (score 0):

Rather than add another button to my form. I have added some Javascript code that will update the OS Grid Reference as the marker is being dragged.